# Derived Category of Arrow Categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, derived-categories

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an abelian category. Then, taking an arrow category does not commute with taking derived categories and this is the main point of a derivator - taking an arrow category first allows for better homotopical properties.

So in general, $D(\mathscr{A}^{[1]}) \not \simeq D(\mathscr{A})^{[1]}$. But why is this true?

I'm not sure what kind of invariants to consider (if any) to distinguish these two categories.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez How do you see this? (Feel free to also post an answer even though it does not answer my question, it is at least interesting and related.)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It seems like your claim is wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazingly, according to [MO/379107](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379107) the arrow category $\mathscr{T}^{[1]}$ of a triangulated category $\mathscr{T}$ has no triangulated structure for $\mathscr{T} \neq 0$.

But $D(\mathscr{A}^{[1]})$ admits a triangulated structure and by the above comment $D(\mathscr{A})^{[1]}$ in general is not. So they cannot be equivalent as categories.

Answer (score 5):

It's not so interesting to ask for these categories to be *inequivalent*, though they surely are. The point is rather than the *obvious* functor is not an equivalence, which means we can't use constructions of cones and such on $D(\mathcal A^{[1]})$ to get such constructions on $D(\mathcal A)^{[1]}.$ The obvious functor is not an equivalence because it is not faithful. Intuitively, this is since morphisms in $D(\mathcal A^{[1]})$ are only equal if there is a homotopy between their defining squares, while morphisms in $D(\mathcal A^{[1]})$ only require homotopies along the edges, which need not cohere together.