Derived Functor Category vs Functors into Derived Category
Given a quiver $Q$, its category of (vect valued) representations is just the functor category $\mathsf{Vect}^Q$. What happens if we want to derive this whole story? There are two natural things to do:

We could derive $\mathsf{Vect}^Q$ to get $D^b(\mathsf{Vect}^Q)$, whose objects are chain complexes which are levelwise $Q$-representations

We could look at the functor ($\infty$-)category $D^b(\mathsf{Vect})^Q$ whose objects are functors from $Q$ valued in chain complexes


I would like to know, perhaps for nice choices of $Q$, whether these are equivalent as stable $\infty$-categories. This seems like the kind of fact that should be in the literature somewhere, but I've looked around and can't find anything. With this in mind, I would also love to know where I can find this fact (and other similar ones) written down.
Of course, if you can push this further I would love to hear it as well! For instance, replacing $Q$ by an algebra $A$ (viewed as a one-object $\mathsf{Vect}$-enriched category) we can recover $A$-mod as a functor category $\mathsf{Vect}^A$. In this context asking if $D^b(\mathsf{Vect}^A) \simeq D^b(\mathsf{Vect})^A$ (restricting to only enriched functors on both sides) is roughly like asking whether $D^b(A\text{-mod})$ is equivalent to chain complex valued representations of $A$... this also sounds believable, but I'm sure there are counterexamples where localizing and taking functors don't commute.
Thanks in advance for any help/references! ^_^

I indeed remember this very discussion (measuring the difference between ho(C^D) and ho(C)^D) being present in a note? draft of book? paper?) of Carlos Simpson on higher categories. It's also a fundamental starting point for the theory of Alexander Grothendieck's or Moritz Groth's derivators. Apologies I can't find a precise ref now, but these might be already effective keywords!

Please do not answer in the comments.

@Shaun (and Martin I suppose) Deleting comments is not the answer.

@Chris Can you clarify whether $\mathbf{D} (\textbf{Vect})$ is supposed to be an ordinary category or an ∞-category?

@ZhenLin I don't delete comments, I cannot. I only flag comments that violate the site guidelines, and then the mods decide what to do with that flag. See How do comments work for more information. Or just read the placeholder text of the comment textbox which is very clear about that answers should not be posted as comments. Maybe next time you can just post an answer to avoid any moderator action. Short answers are also answers.

You are not the judge of what is an answer or not. Only the OP is. In my experience, both on this site and in my professional life, I find that answering questions based on false premises or with clearly incorrect presumptions often does not satisfy the asker, with responses similar to the early stages of grief. I am sure you find it frustrating too when you post an answer and then the asker changes the question because they "obviously" wanted to ask something else.

This is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565566

@ZhenLin -- I'm considering these as $\infty$-categories

The idea that in no interesting example one has $ho(C^J)\simeq ho(C)^J$, for a category with weak equivalences $(C,W)$ and a small diagram category $J$, is at the heart of derivator theory.
references for it:

an historically accurate outline of their theory is in: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~georges.maltsiniotis/groth/Derivateurs.html where you also find a probably very comprehensive bibliography on the topic. Some (negligible) contributions are mine, from the years 2016-2019. Among those in Maltsiniotis page,
The must-read reference is the corpus of work by Moritz Groth, who extended and streamlined the original body of ideas that Groth_endieck_ proposed.

Unfortunately I cannot find confirmation for this vague memory that a book on higher category theory starts with the always big discrepancy between $ho(C^J)$ and $ho(C)^J$ as a motivating example for building the theory. I think it was some writing by C. Simpson.
There are small instances of this: for example, the data encoded in an object of $ho(C^\square)$ (an "homotopy coherently commutative square") is more than just an "incoherent" square. Just because this reference is handy for me, see here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08193 where the point (essential to the theory of derivators) is that "sometimes, enough incoherent data allows to compute a coherent object": in this and in the preceding https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08565 we use this idea to build the notion of what is a "factorization system" on a derivator. It's a factorization system $(E_1,M_1)$ on its "base" $D(1)$, such that some additional data allows to define one, $(E_I,M_I)$, pseudofunctorially, on each $D(I)$.

The answer is completely different depending whether you are thinking of $\mathbf{D} (\textbf{Vect})$ as an ordinary category or a higher category.
As an ordinary category, as several people (including myself) have pointed out, it is considered obvious that even the canonical functor $\mathbf{D} (\textbf{Vect}^{[1]}) \to \mathbf{D} (\textbf{Vect})^{[1]}$ fails to be faithful.
(Here, $[1] = \{ \bullet \to \bullet \}$, the category or quiver with two objects and one arrow between them.)
This is not quite the same as $\mathbf{D} (\textbf{Vect}^{[1]})$ and $\mathbf{D} (\textbf{Vect})^{[1]}$ being inequivalent, but they surely are.
This failure is one of the motivations for inventing higher categories.
I do not work with quasicategories so I cannot give references or proofs in that language, but the translation is well known and what I say is surely in Lurie's Higher Algebra.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with enough projectives, such as the category of left $R$-modules for any ring $R$, or even diagrams thereof.
The bounded derived (∞, 1)-category $\mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A})$ can be modelled by the dg-category of bounded-below chain complexes of projective objects with bounded homology; we obtain a quasicategory by taking the dg-nerve.
(In the case $\mathcal{A}$ is the category of vector spaces over a field, every object is projective, so this is the dg-category of bounded chain complexes; but in general we must be more careful.
The key point is that we need to restrict to a dg-subcategory of either K-projective or K-injective objects to get the right homotopical structure, and we need to be careful about the difference between bounded chain complexes and chain complexes with bounded homology.)
Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a finite category.
Each evaluation functor $\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{A}$ has left and right adjoints, so every projective object in $\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{I}$ is an $\mathcal{I}$-diagram of projective objects in $\mathcal{A}$.
We therefore obtain a canonical dg-functor $\mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{I}) \to \mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A})$ for each object in $\mathcal{I}$, and these are related by canonical natural transformations for each morphism in $\mathcal{I}$.
That is, we have a functor (which is not dg only because $\mathcal{I}$ is not) $\mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{I}) \times \mathcal{I} \to \mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A})$.
If we now think of these as quasicategories, it is the case that the transposed functor $\mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{I}) \to \mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A})^\mathcal{I}$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects.
At the level of dg-categories, what happens is that we have a fully faithful dg-functor from bounded-below chain complexes of projective objects in $\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{I}$ with bounded homology in $\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{I}$ into the dg-category of $\mathcal{I}$-diagrams of chain complexes of bounded-below projective objects in $\mathcal{A}$ with bounded homology.
This dg-functor is not guaranteed to be essentially surjective on objects up to isomorphism, but since $\mathcal{A}$ has enough projectives, it is essentially surjective on objects up to quasi-isomorphism; in other words, we have a Dwyer–Kan equivalence.
(Even if $\mathcal{I}$ is the free category associated with a finite quiver without loops – in which case the homotopy coherence data is redundant for $\mathcal{I}$-diagrams – the morphisms of $\mathcal{I}$-diagrams still have non-trivial homotopy coherence data.)
However, there is a subtle point here.
The quasicategory $\mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A})^\mathcal{I}$ is not literally the dg-nerve of some dg-category of $\mathcal{I}$-diagrams of chain complexes in $\mathcal{A}$.
In fact, the objects of $\mathbf{D}_\mathrm{b} (\mathcal{A})^\mathcal{I}$ are not even $\mathcal{I}$-diagrams of chain complexes: rather, they are homotopy-coherent $\mathcal{I}$-diagrams.
We have to do some additional work (or appeal to more sophisticated results) to justify translating the Dwyer–Kan equivalence mentioned above to an equivalence of quasicategories.
Some of the finiteness restrictions in the above discussion can be lifted if we instead work with the unbounded derived category of, say, the category of left $R$-modules.
There is also a theory of enriched (∞, 1)-categories but this is so far from what I do that I have no idea what parts of the translation are established and what parts are conjectural.
